# Need help using Google map API

Tags: api, google-maps

I have been trying to figure out how to code my page so that when an answer is typed into my form, it searches that answer through a google map API. I can't seem to get the coding right, any help would be greatly appreciated in how I could accomplish my goals! Thanks.

```
<head>
        <!-- This is my first trashy online quiz! -->
            <title>Extra Quiz Information</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1> More about your quiz results!</h1>
    <?php 
        if (isset($_COOKIE['visit_id'])){
            $visit_id = $_COOKIE['visit_id'];
            $all_variables = json_decode(file_get_contents("/var/www/html/data/$visit_id.json"), TRUE);
            //var_dump ($all_variables); 
            echo "<p>";
                echo "Our results show that when you took the quiz: What Environment Suits You? on "; echo $all_variables['timestamp'];
                echo ", <br>you expressed that your favorite place to be in the whole world was: "; echo $all_variables['answer1']; 
            echo "</p>";

            $google_map_stuff = json_decode(file_get_contents echo <a href="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=', urlencode($all_variables['answer1'])">, TRUE);
            echo $google_map_stuff["results"][0]["types"][0];
            //var_dump($google_map_stuff);
        } else {
            echo "You have not yet taken the quiz titled: What Environment Suits You?<br>
            Please "; echo '<a href="roate1-form.html">take it now</a>'; echo " and then return to this page after you have finished.";
        }

                ?>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an error message?  You really shouldn't call the API the way that you are.  If you want to use the web services API you should do it from your server.  Otherwise, if you want to use Javascript please review the [Google Maps Javascript API reference (I linked you straight to the geocoder reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Geocoder).

I won't bore you with my code and instead give you a direct link to the [Google code samples page.](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/)